# Разрешить RDP подключение для пользователя с определённых IP в Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server, windows-server-2016

ОС - Windows Server 2016. Так же используется система контроля домена.

Возникла необходимость ограничить доступ для RDP подключения для нескольких пользователей *(или если такой гибкости нет, то для всех)* и разрешить подключение по RDP только с определённых IP-адресов, по возможности на весь домен, что бы при необходимости изменить список, применялось на все машины внутри домена.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь. За ранее спасибо

Comment: Эммм... у тебя все пользователи состоят в группе `Пользователи удалённого рабочего стола`? О_о

Comment: @donRumata , Да, так же все состоят в группе *Domain Users*. Из этих пользователей, части нужно разрешить вход только с определённых IP адресов. По логике я понимаю что нужно добавить их в отдельную группу и настроить брандмауэр или провести другую настройку для группы, но какую и как не знаю

Comment: А почему важна привязка именно к ip? Почему не устраивает только логины? Если не знать пару `логин\пасс` того, кто состоит в группе удалённых рабочих столов - зайти всё равно будет невозможно.

Comment: С целью безопастности. **логин\пасс** можно где-то засветить, а привязка к IP надёжней

Comment: Вроде бы давно уже поставляется решение в составе серверов- шлюз удаленных рабочих столов (RD GATEWAY SERVICE). Благодаря ему можно отлично разграничивать пользователей по группам, назначать сертификаты (которыми тоже можно гибко управлять), выносить сервисы за периметр предприятия и т.д.

Comment: Тогда ищи ещё и привязку к маку, потому что ip тоже можно подменить. Как впрочем и мак.

Answer (score 0):

***Изменение существующего правила брандмауэра***

1. Подключитесь к своему серверу через RDP или через консоль.
2. Откройте Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Нажмите Inbound
   Rules на левой панели.
3. Найдите правило RDP (Remote Desktop). Щелкните правило правой
   кнопкой мыши, перейдите в Properties, перейдите на вкладку Scope.

***Создать ограничения по IP***

На вкладке **Scope** вы добавляете IP-адреса и диапазоны, к которым вы хотите получить доступ к серверу.

1. На вкладке Scope отредактируйте раздел Remote IP Address.
2. Нажмите кнопку рядом с These IP Addresses
3. Затем нажмите Add ...
4. Если вы используете один IP-адрес, просто введите его в текстовое
   поле выше и нажмите OK.
5. Для каждого дополнительного IP-адреса повторите шаги 3 и 4.
6. Если вам нужно добавить диапазон IP-адресов, нажмите кнопку рядом с This IP range
7. Введите начало диапазона в поле From и конец диапазона в поле To.
8. Для каждого дополнительного диапазона повторите шаги 6 и 7.